# Cannot Run node in vscode terminal

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, npm, terminal

why i cannot run Node in my vscode terminal anybody know?
sorry im a newbie, im currently using POP OS 22.04
[image: VSCODE TERMINAL][image: Node and NPM version]

I hope anybody can help my problem

Answer (score 0):

Did you install node just before using vs code terminal? If yes, try restarting vs code or restart your system .

Comment: FIXED, I re-install the deb version (i was using flatpak version in this pic)

Answer (score -1):

Fixed With re-installing deb version(i was using flakpak version before)
[Fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZlQM.png)